# Filling a CSV file with python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to working with python and I wanted to know how to fill specific rows and columns in a new csv file with data from a preexisting csv file.

```
import csv
with open('Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in reader:
     print ', '.join(row)
with open('Franchise_Name_Scrub_List.csv', 'rb') as f1, \
 open('FACTS_bronto_import_add.csv', 'ab') as f2:
next(f1)
f2.writelines(f1)
```

Comment: yep.  tell us that.  Otherwise we can't answer your question as per policy.

Comment: As a hint you might want to see what `import csv` does as well as how to open files and read data from them.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that i have that i have tried

Comment: If that's how your code is indented you are going to have some problems.

Comment: You are opening the read file twice but you never closed it.  Did you mean to seek back to the start. You also do nothing with row. Did you mean to output the comma separated rows to f2 or did you indeed mean to just copy the original space separated rows in f1 (without the header row) to f2?  It appears that you are trying to add the contents of f1 to what is already in f2 which would explain why you skip the header row, but how do you check to ensure that this is not the first time so that you need the header row?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to write to another file excluding the header, then you don't need the `csv` module at all, for instance:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(islice(fin, 1, None))
```